# react JS how to make theme-able component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to decide the best route to go for distributing a component that others can theme. They may need to change the html structure as well as the css/bootstrap styling. (I am using react-bootstrap with the component.

The only way I can see to do this is to make a component folder with all of the subcomponents in `src/themes/default`, `src/themes/awesome`, etc and then import them into the main component which people can then call by doing something like this...

**This is just a concept, it probably isn't completely valid**

```
import default from './themes/default/index.js`
import awesome from './themes/awesome/index.js`

const themes = {
  default,
  aweosme,
} 

const MyComponent = ({ theme, otherprop }) => {
  return (
    <themes.default otherprop={otherprop} />
  )
}
```

then if someone wanted to contribute a theme, they would have to write a whole component complete with html structure in the jsx and inline styles to go along with it. It would require them to be familiar with react, but I cannot see another way to do it unless I have missed something...

What do you think?

Comment: can the theme be changed at run-time after the application is built and running ?? and are you using any css frameworks like foundation or bootstrap ??

Comment: hmm I hadn't thought about that so I have to say maybe.

Comment: if those are the case then you are better of building the app first and using the theme generator of either bootstrap or foundation to generate theme for it ( and may add some extra theme for custom class to later)

Comment: but couldn't the caller of the component make the theme string part of their state which would then cause it to be re-rendered on the fly?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question....the theme structure cannot be changed after the app is built...but the theme itself can be switch to another theme after being built

Comment: In that case I would suggest to go with theme generators.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155563/discussion-between-user93-and-deltaskelta).

Comment: do you have an example you can post? I am not familiar with what you are talking about

Comment: Material-ui has done this using `context` which is very applicable to such use cases. They have provided the applicable HOCs and wrapper components per the context best practices. Reading there implementation should help.